# Dropwizard Environement variables

Tags: java, jersey, environment-variables, dropwizard

I am having problems finding good resources for the dropwizard environment configuration, the manuals from dropwizard are not really helpful for me.

I am trying to save my `jwtSecret` in my configuration `config.yml` as a environment variable so it stays a secret even if I make my code open source as

```
jwtSecret: ${JWT_SECRET}
```

I have read the [manuals](https://www.dropwizard.io/en/latest/manual/core.html#environment-variables) and I know I need to add `SubstitutingSourceProvider` to successfully substitute the config with my environment variables. However I do not find where to save my environment variables. Is there a specific place where dropwizard finds it or do I need to add the path to the environment variables somewhere?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure which part you need help with, but adding environmental variables touches many points.

First we enable this feature by adding it to the Application's initialize function:

```
bootstrap.setConfigurationSourceProvider(new SubstitutingSourceProvider(bootstrap.getConfigurationSourceProvider(), new EnvironmentVariableSubstitutor(false)));
```

Then there is the config.yml:

```
jwtSecret: ${JWT_SECRET}
```

To access the variable in your application, you need to add this to the Application's Configuration class:

```
private String jwtSecret;
```

(+ getter and setter for it)

And lastly you need to add the JWT_SECRET variable to your system environmental variables. This varies based on which operating system you are using and whether you want to set it temporarily or permanently.

Comment: Is it possible to have an .env file in my project to save the environment variables there or do I need to save it in my .zshrc?

Comment: It depends how you run the application. For example, I use IntelliJ for development and I have configured the environmental variables in IntelliJ's project Run Configuration window, if I run the application from a java package outside of IntelliJ, I first run a shell script that has environmental values configured and then run the package -- so I don't have them in my .bashrc either. On my staging and prod environments they have been configured for the k8s container.